# django alternative for using getloadavg

Tags: django

I want do show the load average 1' 5' 15' in the dashboard in my django app.

```
try:
    data = os.getloadavg()
except Exception as err:
    data = str(err)
```

throws an exception. But it works in a python console. Is there another way to get the information?

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: The exception is not the problem, but I'm looking an alternative to the function...

Comment: 'function' object has no attribute 'getloadavg' is the exception

Comment: That means you are reassigning `os` somewhere in the function or scope that calls that. Nothing to do with Django.

Comment: Either way, a nonportable way that works on Linux at least is to open `/proc/loadavg` and parse it. But I really think you should use `os.getloadavg()`.

Comment: I don't think that I'm reassigning 'os', I do not import it just use it as shown in the question.

Comment: You have the name `os` assigned to a function, that's clear from the exception. Are you sure you don't have e.g. `def os(): ...`?

Comment: psutil is the answer

Comment: I still don't see _why_ you need an alternative, since there's nothing wrong with `os.getloadavg()`.